# Проект не запускается

Tags: android, kotlin

Ошибку покажу на скрине[image: Скриншот ошибок]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/math_operation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonAC"
                style="@style/ActionButton"
                android:text="AC"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonG"
                style="@style/ActionButton"
                android:text="("
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonR"
                style="@style/ActionButton"
                android:text=")"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonD"
                style="@style/ActionButton"
                android:text="/"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                style="@style/ActionButton"
                android:text="1"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                style="@style/ActionButton"
                android:text="2"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                style="@style/ActionButton"
                android:text="3"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonU"
                style="@style/ActionButton"
                android:text="*"
                />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                style="@style/ActionButton"
                android:text="4"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                style="@style/ActionButton"
                android:text="5"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                style="@style/ActionButton"
                android:text="6"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonP"
                style="@style/ActionButton"
                android:text="+"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                style="@style/ActionButton"
                android:text="7"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                style="@style/ActionButton"
                android:text="8"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                style="@style/ActionButton"
                android:text="9"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonUd"
                style="@style/ActionButton"
                android:text="-"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonDr"
                style="@style/ActionButton"
                android:text="."
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button0"
                style="@style/ActionButton"
                android:text="0"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonB"
                style="@style/ActionButton"
                android:text="Back"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonRo"
                style="@style/ActionButton"
                android:text="="
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Ошибка:

```
ERROR:AAPT: C:\Users\v.vershinin\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidKotlin\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1120: error: expected reference but got (raw string) #d60b26.
C:\Users\v.vershinin\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidKotlin\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2104: error: style attribute 'android:attr/dialogCornerRadius' not found.
C:\Users\v.vershinin\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidKotlin\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:15: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
C:\Users\v.vershinin\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidKotlin\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:15: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
C:\Users\v.vershinin\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidKotlin\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:19: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
C:\Users\v.vershinin\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidKotlin\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:19: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
C:\Users\v.vershinin\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidKotlin\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3090: error: expected reference but got (raw string) #DFDFDF.
C:\Users\v.vershinin\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidKotlin\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3092: error: expected color reference but got (raw string) #fffff.
C:\Users\v.vershinin\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidKotlin\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:6513: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
C:\Users\v.vershinin\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidKotlin\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:6514: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
C:\Users\v.vershinin\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidKotlin\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:6845: error: resource android:attr/lineHeight not found.
C:\Users\v.vershinin\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidKotlin\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:6851: error: resource android:attr/lineHeight not found.
C:\Users\v.vershinin\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidKotlin\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:7613: error: resource android:attr/textFontWeight not found.
error: failed linking references.
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: ошибку текстом приложить нужно, и градл файлы приложите пож

Comment: ваша ошибка выглядит так - `error: style attribute 'android:attr/dialogCornerRadius' not found`, вот здесь описывается подобная проблема - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49280632/error9-5-error-resource-androidattr-dialogcornerradius-not-found

Comment: @Andrew подскажите пожалуйста где взять gradle файлы?

Comment: у вас в проекте они есть) `build.gradle` называются, вам нужно приложить их в тело вопроса